# Get Prime Number records in Oracle using ROWNUM

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get all the prime(row) numbered records from my table.Can someone please shed some light on how to solve this problem?

Here is my sample data as below.

```
EMPID EMPNAME
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E
6 F
7 G
8 H
9 I
10 J
```

Required output:

```
EMPID EMPNAME
2 B 
3 C
5 E
7 G
```

If I have huge data how do I get the output like this instead of using IN operator?

Comment: Homework, or real-world application?

Comment: Its a real-time application I am working on...

Comment: I doubt there's a pre-built function to generate prime numbers.

Comment: I tried searching for it on google.. but couldn't find anything exactly as I require..

Comment: Is your question how to generate a list of prime numbers, or is it how to filter rows given an arbitrary list of "row numbers" to select?

Comment: @DaveCosta I have some 'n' number of rows in my table starting from 1 to 'n'. Now I would like to retrieve only the prime numbered records.

Comment: If this is not homework, i.e. related to a real business need, I'll eat the hat on my head. Care to elaborate, Venk? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

```
CREATE TABLE primes (
    num number PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO primes (num)
SELECT LEVEL + 1
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 1000;

DELETE FROM primes p1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM primes p2
    WHERE p2.num < p1.num
    AND MOD(p1.num, p2.num) = 0
);
```

And then

```
SELECT emps.*
FROM emps
INNER JOIN primes ON primes.num = emps.EMPID;
```

Or

```
SELECT EMPID, EMPNAME
FROM (
    SELECT ROWNUM AS rn, emps.EMPID, emps.EMPNAME
    FROM emps
)
INNER JOIN primes ON primes.num = rn;
```

If you don't want to calculate the primes, you could add them from existing data: [List of small primes](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/)

Comment: This creates a table with exactly one row (num = 1) for me?

Comment: Right. Forgot about '1' being in the table. Updated the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
select l prime_number
      from (select level l from dual connect by level <= 100)
         , (select level m from dual connect by level <= 100)
    -- where m<=l  --this doesnt matter but including it will perform better
     group by l
   having count(case l/m when trunc(l/m) then 1 end) in (1,2)
     order by l;
```

PRIME_NUMBER 
1 
2 
3 
5 
7 
11 
13 
17 
19 
23 
29 
31 
37 
41 
43 
47 
53 
59 
61 
67 
71 
73 
79 
83 
89 
97

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to Select all prime numbers

```
SQL> select l prime_number
  2    from (select level l from dual connect by level <= 100)
  3       , (select level m from dual connect by level <= 100)
  4   where m<=l
  5   group by l
  6  having count(case l/m when trunc(l/m) then 'Y' end) = 2
  7   order by l
  8  /

                          PRIME_NUMBER

                                     2
                                     3
                                     5
                                     7
                                    11
                                    13
                                    17
                                    19
                                    23
                                    29
                                    31
                                    37
                                    41
                                    43
                                    47
                                    53
                                    59
                                    61
                                    67
                                    71
                                    73
                                    79
                                    83
                                    89
                                    97
```

or this one:

```
SQL> with t as (select level l from dual connect by level <= 100)
  2  --
  3  SELECT l prim_num FROM
  4     (select * from t
  5       model
  6        dimension by (l dim)
  7        measures (l,2 temp)
  8         rules iterate (1000000) until (power(temp[1],2)>100)
  9           (l[DIM>TEMP[1]]=decode(mod(l[CV()],temp[1]),0,null,l[CV()]),
 10            temp[1]=min(l)[dim>temp[1]])
 11     )
 12  WHERE l IS NOT NULL
 13  /
```

and then just do this:

```
Select * 
from myTable 
where ROWNUM in (query)
```

Comment: It looks pretty; but your last query will not work... rownum is a psuedo column only calculated on the result-set. You'd have to take the rownum out in a sub-select and then join to your query...

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used:

```
with lvl as
(
  select level l from dual connect by level<=100
), unprime as(select l2.* from lvl l1,lvl l2 where l1.l<l2.l and mod(l2.l,l1.l)=0 and l1.l>1)
select lvl.l from lvl where l>1
minus select l from unprime;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow MOULINDRA. It's better if you explain your answer. Code only answers are not considered good and probably can't help people understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Prime numbers up to 10 can be listed belows. Then join with your data on EMPID.

```
(SELECT LEVEL P FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM<=10)
MINUS
(SELECT T1.P FROM
  (SELECT LEVEL P FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM<=10) T1 JOIN
  (SELECT LEVEL D FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM<=10) T2 ON mod(T1.P,T2.D)=0 AND T1.P>T2.D 
AND T2.D>1
)
MINUS (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL);
```

Assuming your table name is EMP:

```
WITH EMP AS
(
    SELECT 1 EMPID, 'A' EMPNAME FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 EMPID, 'B' EMPNAME FROM DUAL
    --etc.
)
SELECT EMP.* FROM 
(
    (SELECT LEVEL P FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM<=10)
    MINUS
    (SELECT T1.P FROM
      (SELECT LEVEL P FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM<=10) T1 JOIN
      (SELECT LEVEL D FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM<=10) T2 ON mod(T1.P,T2.D)=0 AND T1.P>T2.D 
    AND T2.D>1
    )
    MINUS (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL)
) T1,EMP WHERE T1.P=EMP.EMPID;
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The user wants to get rows from a table, not a number result.

Comment: @ConnorLow thanks. I edited my answer to show the final resultset.