# procedure with CTE (such as with clause)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I want to calculate prime number using PL/SQL. I modified from previous post
[Get Prime Number records in Oracle using ROWNUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915375/get-prime-number-records-in-oracle-using-rownum).

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FindBP(pHigh NUMBER) IS
non BOOLEAN; 
Begin
 FOR p IN 2..pHigh
 LOOP non := true;

with t as(select level l from dual connect by level <= pHigh)
if(
p in
(select l from (select * from  t
model     
dimension by (l dim)
measures (l,2 temp)
rules iterate (1000000)
until (power(temp[1],2)>100)     
(l[DIM>TEMP[1]]=decode(mod(l[CV()],temp[1]),0,null,l[CV()]),
temp[1]=min(l)[dim>temp[1]])
 ) where l is not NULL)

 then non := FALSE; end if;

IF (NOT non) 
      THEN INSERT INTO N VALUES (p); 
     END IF;
 END LOOP; 
END;
```

However, I found that with_clause might not work, so I try to use sql below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FindBP(pHigh NUMBER) IS
non BOOLEAN; 
Begin
 FOR p IN 2..pHigh
 LOOP non := true;

If( p in (select * from (select level l from dual connect by level<=pHigh) t
   model
   dimension by (l dim)
   measures (l,2 temp)     
   rules iterate (1000000) until (power(temp[1],2)>100)     
   (l[DIM>TEMP[1]]=decode(mod(l[CV()],temp[1]),0,null,l[CV()]),        
   temp[1]=min(l)[dim>temp[1]])
 ) then non := FALSE; end if;

     IF (NOT non) 
      THEN INSERT INTO N VALUES (p); 
     END IF;
 END LOOP; 

END;
```

Neither of them pass the compilation. Any idea please?
For the first one, I got error

```
error(7,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

For the second one, I got

```
error(8,8): PLS-00103: "MODEL"   , with    group having intersect minus start union where connect
```

Comment: As before, please include the errors you get as part of the question. Thanks. You seem to be mixing SQL and Pl/SQL syntax though.

Comment: Hey, Alex. Thanks for the insight thought. I read from somewhere saying one can run sql inside a pl/sql. Therefore, I wonder is it the right format.

Comment: You can, but you can't use  PL/SQL 'if' in SQL, or SQL inside  PL/SQL 'if'. [Read more about how they interact](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the material. Is there quick way that I can use the previous post'method in my PL/SQL please?